# python geocoding with ClientID and secret key

Tags: python, geocoding

I understand there are existing python libraries like this one https://github.com/DenisCarriere/geocoder to handle geocoding need, however it is only for regular user using API Key, we are not using API Key, we purchased business license, meaning we use ClientID and secret key and must go through some crypto process to get the result, detailed here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-api-key#client-id.

We have million records to process and time cost is a big concern, any suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know about python libraries for Google's API, but if you really need a solution fast, SmartyStreets (https://smartystreets.com) has an API that does geocoding. I'm a software developer at SmartyStreets, and I built their python library. A million addresses might take about 15 minutes or so.

Comment: Thank you, we are looking for Google API solution.